# ¿Que maneras existen de comunicarse entre formularios de Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

buenos días gente de Stack Overflow, vengo hoy para consultarles las maneras que hay de comunicarse en tiempo real entre formularios de Windows Forms, necesito ser capaz de establecer valores a las variables, llamar a métodos y poder mostrar u ocultar los formularios, procedo a explicarles cómo lo hice hasta ahora.

Suponiendo que tenga un formulario llamado Form1 el cual quiero comunicar con el formulario llamado Form2, lo que hago es lo siguiente.

> En el Botón que muestra el segundo formulario, va el siguen código.

```
private void BotonForm2_onClick()
{
   Form2 FormularioNuevo = new Form2(this);
   FormularioNuevo.show;
   this.hide;
}
```

> En el constructor del segundo formulario va el siguente código.

```
public Form1 FormularioAnterior { get; set }

public Form2(Form formulario)
{
   Initialize components();
   FormularioAnterior = formulario as Form2;
}
```

Y desfea variable FormularioAnterior es de donde modifico las variables y llamo a los métodos, ¿Es correcto?, ¿Hay mejor manera?, ¿Se puede optimizar?, Desde ya, muchas gracias!

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Con el tema y el enunciado de la pregunta me estoy refiriendo a una comunicación en tiempo real, del estilo websocket entre formularios, que yo desde un formulario pueda editar por ejemplo los controles del otro, los textos de los botones por dar un ejemplo, y esto todo al instante, muchas gracias nuevamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que por comunicarse en tiempo real entre formularios de `Windows Forms`, estés hablando de pasar valores de variables definidas en el `Form1` pasarlas a `Form2` y además devolver valores desde `Form2`, que puedan ser usados en el entorno de `Form1`.

Para ello en tu código hay varias cosas que no son lo más aconsejable.

1-Primero no necesitas crear la propiedad `public Form1 FormularioAnterior { get; set }`, en el `Form2`, pues un objeto Windows Forms, tiene las propiedades `Parent` y `Owner` que pueden perfectamente almacenar la referencia a `Form1`, si es que necesitaras acceder a ella.

2-Para pasar variables definidas en `Form1`, al `Form2` una forma de hacerlo, es pasarlas como argumento al constructor de `Form2`.

3-Para recuperar valores de `Form2` en el entorno de `Form1`, ver el evento `formHijo_FormClosed`.

Código en `Form1`.

```
//Variable que se pasará a Form2.
private object varbl1, varbl2;

private void BotonForm2_onClick()
{
   //Crear el Form2, pasar como argumentos varbl1, varbl2
   //Asignar su valor a la variable local formHijo 
   this.formHijo = new Form2(varbl1, varbl2);
   //Llamar el metodo Show
   this.formHijo.Show();

  //Crear el evento FormClosed
        this.formHijo.FormClosed+=new FormClosedEventHandler(formHijo_FormClosed);

   this.hide;
}
    //Evento FormClosed del Form2
    void formHijo_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
      Form2 formHijo = sender as Form2;
      //Recuperar el valor de propiedades definidas en Form2
    object valor1 = formHijo.Propd1Form2;
    object valor2 = formHijo.Propd2Form2;
     //Mostrar Form1
     this.Show();
    }
```

Código en `Form2`.

```
//Variables que vienen de Form1
private object var1deForm1, var2deForm1;

public Form2(object Val1, object Val2)
{
   Initialize components();
   this.var1deForm1 = Val1;
   this.var2deForm1 = Val2;
}
public object Propd1Form2{ get; set }
public object Propd2Form2{ get; set }
```

De esta forma estarías pasando valores desde `Form1` a `Form2` y devolviendo valores desde `Form2` que puedes usar en `Form1`, existen otras formas de hacerlo que puedes aprender investigando.

Comment: Gracias Eduardo, me ha servido el ejemplo que me has mandado, saludos y gracias nuevamente!

Comment: @GuillermoMarighetti Gracias por aceptar mi respuesta, como la mejor, es un estimulo para mi pues soy nuevo en el sitio y además, desarrollador autodidacta. Solo agregar que si lo crees justo, me gustaría que puntearas mi respuesta.

Comment: Cuando me habiliten nuevamente para puntear (8hs) recibirás tu merecido mérito, Saludos!

Comment: @GuillermoMarighetti Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Actualizo la respuesta en base a tu pregunta actualizada.

Puedes entrar a la clase Form2.Designer.cs y colocar los controles que quieran cambiar la propiedad como publicos, ejemplo:

```
    public System.Windows.Forms.Button btn_Crear;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt_dni;
    private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox imagenQr;
```

Luego instancias la clase form2:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.btn_crear.Text = "Texto";
```

---

Para enviar valores entre formularios deberias usar clases de tus modelos creados y no la clase form, ya que estas pasando valores que no tienen nada que ver con lo que necesitas.

```
public class MiClase
{
  public string nombre {get;set;}
}
```

---

```
MiClase _miclase = new MiClase();
private void BotonForm2_onClick()
{
   _miClase.nombre = "prueba";
   Form2 FormularioNuevo = new Form2(_miclase);
   FormularioNuevo.show;
   this.hide;
}
```

---

```
MiClase _miclase;

public Form2(MiClase miclase)
{
   Initialize components();
   _miclase = miclase;
}
```

Otra forma es usando clases Static, esta clase no necesita instanciarse para poder usar sus propiedades y valores cargados.

```
  public static class MiClase
    {
      public string nombre {get;set;}
    }
```

3 opcion: es pasar al formulario tal cual lo haces pero un objeto que lleve los parametros necesarios y en el constructor recorres los valores y vas asignando.

```
public Form2(miClase _miclase)
{
  InitializeComponent();
  VerificarControles(_miclase);
}

private void VerificarControles(MiClase _miclase)
{
   if(_miclase.TextoBoton != string.Empty)
   {
     btn1.Text = _miclase.TextoBoton;
   }
```

Comment: Hola Ramiro, lo que busco es una comunicación constante, una especie de websocket entre formularios, donde los cambios se apliquen en tiempo real entre formularios, agradezco tu respuesta igualmente.

Comment: tenes que editar la pregunta, para explicar bien que cambios queres que se produzcan